# Spring Boot @PrePersist does not work properly

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, sql-null

I have a Spring Boot application with Kotlin and want to store the creation timestamp and the last updated timestamp. The following code should do the trick:

```
@Entity
data class Entity(
// ...
) {
    lateinit var createdAt: Instant
    lateinit var updatedAt: Instant

    @PrePersist
    private fun onCreate() {
        createdAt = Instant.now().also { updatedAt = it }
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private fun onUpdate() {
        updatedAt = Instant.now()
    }
}
```

The PostgreSQL table looks like this:

```
create table entity
(
    -- Other fields...

    created_at    timestamp not null,
    updated_at    timestamp not null
);
```

When i now try to call `repository.save(entity)` I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint
```

`updatedAt` however has the correct value which means `@PreUpdate` is working as expected. Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: I would say it's this line Instant.now().also { updatedAt = it }

Comment: @SimonMartinelli What's the problem here? I've also tried setting them separately to Instant.now()

Comment: @IanFako please share a more specific example that fails as this seems like an abstract version of your code which should not be failing. Probably in your specific code exists some issue which is not shown here.